# ParentStackBuilder Notification Android

Tags: android, notifications, stack

I'm developing an Android app and I'm struggling to get it behaves in the right way regarding notifications to the user.

I followed literally this [tutorial](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/notifiers/notifications.html) but I can't reproduce this case:

Suppose I'm in Activity A, and my stack is like **B-->A.** 
    I press home button. 
    A notification arrives which bring me to Activity A
    I open the notif and so the activity A
    When I press back I come back to the old A instead of coming back to B.
    It's like my stack is **B-->A-->A** instead of **B-->A**

I added the parent of A in the manifest, the only thing I wasn't able to do is adding the parentActivityName flag because it is not supported in old Android. For the rest my code is identical to the linked in the tutorial for a regular activity.

I even tried to launch my **PendingIntent** with the **FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT** but it seems not to work.

Thanks for your time!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP`

Comment: But this will start the activity in a new task, I want to preserve the old stack

Comment: No, the document states "When using this flag, if a task is already running for the activity you are now starting, then a new activity will not be started; instead, the current task will simply be brought to the front of the screen with the state it was last in"

Comment: But if your stack is A --> B then you will only get A now

Comment: Clear top only clear whatever on top of A but you have no A yet that is why you have your stack as above.

Comment: Ok but suppose I have B-->A-->C-->D and now the notification arrives. I expect now my stack to be ParentOfA-->A instead I get B-->C-->D-->A like if the CLEAR_TOP wasn't working, C and D should be destroyed

Comment: That is strange you should get B --> A

Comment: This is the document for clear top "For example, consider a task consisting of the activities: A, B, C, D. If D calls startActivity() with an Intent that resolves to the component of activity B, then C and D will be finished and B receive the given Intent, resulting in the stack now being: A, B."

Comment: Remove the FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK and see if you get B --> A

Comment: I don't know it does not hurt to try. I am going to sleep, if you get to behave the way you want let me know.

Comment: Have a good night and thanks! By the way I think now it is only a matter of trial and errors to get the desired behave, your answer is totally right